# How to get all primary key with a specific name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get all primary key of a database when their name are `exactly = "ID"`

My goal is to retrieve all of this keys for a refactoring. I have tried with the table `information_schema` but cannot achieve my goal by myself.

The most prefered output should be:

```
SCHEMA_NAME     |   TABLE_NAME      |   PRIMARY_KEY_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME = TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TABLE_NAME,
       PRIMARY_KEY_NAME = CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ID'
```

or use `sys.key_constraints`

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME= s.NAME,
       TABLE_NAME = Object_name(kc.parent_object_id),
       PRIMARY_KEY_NAME = kc.NAME
FROM   sys.key_constraints kc
       JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON kc.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE  type = 'pk'
       AND kc.NAME = 'ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Col.Column_Name, col.CONSTRAINT_NAME from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
 WHERE 
Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND col.CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%adhoc%'
```